# Is this proper behavior? std::map iterator invalidation

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::map<int, int> map;
  map.emplace(1, 1);
  auto reverse_iter = map.rbegin();
  std::cout << reverse_iter->first << ", " << reverse_iter->second << std::endl;
  map.emplace(2, 2);
  std::cout << reverse_iter->first << ", " << reverse_iter->second << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This prints out:

```
1, 1
2, 2
```

Is this really what's supposed to happen, according to the standard?  I'm not touching reverse_iter but the value it's pointing to is changing. I thought iterators in std::map were supposed to be safe against insertion. Yet it seems to be deciding that reverse_iter is not to stay pointing to the value I told it to, rather to "whatever happens to be at the end of the map at this point in time".

Update: further info, in case it matters: this doesn't seem to happen with forward iterators (in any situation I can seem to find), and my gcc version is 5.1.1-4.

Comment: Being "invalidated" and pointing to new data are not the same thing, are they? It's a valid pointer to the last pair in your container. That pair just happens to have changed.

Comment: Doesn't happen with forward iterators. Replace rbegin with begin and replace (2, 2) with (0, 0). And again, is that standards-compliant? Because it's really darned unexpected, that's for sure.

Comment: Right, the first thing you put in the map won't change. However the last thing you did will.

Comment: Nothing in the map is changing - what the iterator points to is changing, without me touching the iterator. Why? Is that standards compliant?  An iterator is designed to be like a pointer - you point it to something and it stays pointing there and stays valid until you point it to something else or it gets invalidated. And indeed, that's what seems to happen with forward iterators. But not reverse. How does this make sense?  It's a huge problem to using reverse iterators in any sort of non-const context.

Comment: There is no iterator invalidation; the regular `iterator` your `reverse_iterator` contains is the `end()` iterator, and that is remaining valid even after the `emplace`. When you dereference the `reverse_iterator` it decrements the `end()` iterator and dereferences the result, which gives you the output you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quoted here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/rbegin

> Reverse iterator stores an iterator to the next element than the one it actually refers to

the side effect would be that if you insert something before that iterator (incliding end()) you will see that new value when you dereference that reverse iterator. I do not think that reverse iterator is invalidated in this case.

Comment: So, basically, it's broken by design?  :Þ  Changes to something next to an iterator you're using can change the iterator you're using?  

Great...  :Þ

But, if that's what the standard says, nothing I can do.

Comment: I think you're confusing "valid" and "consistent". Invalid is a very specific thing, it means the iterator should not be used as it will cause undefined behaviour. Your expectations that what the iterator points to will not change after manipulating the map are not being met, but that's not a problem with the standard.

Comment: Given that the whole purpose of iterators is to act as a replacement for pointers and indexing, I'd say that a standard that has them change when you're modifying something that they're not pointing to is very broken.  I'd also say that having behavior inconsistent between forward and reverse iterators is also very broken.  But it is what it is.

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ Standard (23.2.4 Associative containers)

> 9 The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of
>   iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall
>   invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

On the other hand (24.5.1 Reverse iterators)

> 1 Class template reverse_iterator is an iterator adaptor that iterates
>   from the end of the sequence defined by its underlying iterator to the
>   beginning of that sequence.

Though in the last quote there is said about class `std::reverse_iterator` the same is valid for reverse iterators of standard containers.

According to  Table 97 — Reversible container requirements

`rbegin()` corresponds to `reverse_iterator(end())`

So in your example the reverse iterator still corresponds to `end()`.
`

Answer (score 1):

`map.rbegin()` returns an iterator that is equal to `std::reverse_iterator(map.end());`

The problem arises when you dereference a reverse iterator. When you dereference a `reverse_iterator` the value you actually get is from the iterator before the one is stored inside the `reverse_iterator`. That might seem strange, but is there for good reasons, and it's unavoidable.  This is so, in order to arrange for the past-the-end element of a range: An iterator pointing to a past-the-end element in a range, when reversed, is pointing to the last element (not past it) of the range (this would be the first element of the reversed range). And if an iterator to the first element in a range is reversed, the reversed iterator points to the element before the first element (this would be the past-the-end element of the reversed range).

That is, in your case when dereferencing the `reverse_iter` is equivalent with doing:

```
*(--map.end());
```

Consequently, after the second `emplace` the last element of the map has changed and dereferencing `(--map.end())` (i.e., your `reverse_iter`) you get the new last element in the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map<int, int> map2;
map2.emplace(2, 2);
auto fiter = map2.begin();
std::cout << fiter->first << ", " << fiter->second << std::endl;
map2.emplace(1, 1);
std::cout << fiter->first << ", " << fiter->second << std::endl;
fiter = map2.begin();
std::cout << fiter->first << ", " << fiter->second << std::endl;
```

prints

```
2, 2
2, 2
1, 1
```